Canonical 1-form on the frame bundle $FM$
Let $\omega: T(FM)\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the map defined by $\omega(u, v) = u(D\pi_u(v))$ where $\pi: FM\to M$ is the natural projection that sends the isomorphism $u:T_xM\to \mathbb{R}^n$ to $x$, i.e. $\pi(u)=x$ (note $u\in FM$). I am asked to check why $\omega$ is a smooth $\mathbb{R}^n-$valued $1$-form. I understand that the map works, that is, it is the composition $$T_{u}(FM)\xrightarrow{\ D\pi_u\ \ }T_{\pi(u)}M\xrightarrow{\ u\ }\mathbb{R}^n$$
I see why this is smooth for each $u$, but I don't understand why is $\omega$ smooth (when $u$ varies). Any help is appreciated.

I will consider all the problem locally. For instance, just assume that $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ and try to write everything. A manifold is just Euclidean spaces glued together, so if one proves that something is smooth on the Euclidean space, and if it is globally defined on the whole manifold, then it becomes smooth globally.

If $(x,e_1,\dots,e_n)$ is a local frame on $M$, what are your $(u,v)$ and $\omega$?

I'm not sure. Is $u$ simply an element of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$? So if we assumed $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ then $FM \cong GL_n(\mathbb{R})$? But I thought $FM$ locally looks like $U\times GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ so maybe  $ FM \cong \mathbb{R}^n\times GL_n(\mathbb{R}) $?

I believe that this notation means: $u\in FM$ and $v\in T_uFM$. You do not correctly understand what the frame bundle is. $u$ is a frame at $x=\pi(u)$, i.e., an isomorphism $T_xM\to\Bbb R^n$. Now can you answer my earlier question? (It might be helpful to define the $1$-forms dual to the basis ${e_i}$.)

Sorry, I am still confused. When you write $(x, e_1,...,e_n)$ is a local frame on $M$, do you mean a map from $T_xM\to \mathbb{R}^n$ where the basis elements of $T_xM$ are mapped to $e_1,...,e_n$, the standard basis elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

No, the $e_i$ are typically the inverse image of the standard basis vectors.

Try $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ first. Then we have $TM=\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n$, $FM=\mathbb{R}^n\times GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, $T(FM)=T\mathbb{R}^n\times TGL_n(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\times GL_n(\mathbb{R})\times M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $\omega$ is mapping $(x,v,X,V)$ to $X(v)$, which is obviously smooth since it is just an algebraic(i.e. polynomial) map. Note that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is just $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ minus the zero set of the determinant, which is again a polynomial.
Now for an arbitrary smooth manifold $M$, suppose a local differomorphism $\phi:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to M$ is given. We know that $w_{U}$ is well-defined. We want to show that the pull back of $w_M|_{\phi(U)}$ is exactly $w_U$. Choose $(x,u,v)\in T(FM)$. We need to compare $w_M(x,u,v)=u(d\pi_M(v))$ and $w_u({(\phi^{-1})}^*(x,u,v))$, where $(\phi^{-1})^*:TFM \to TFU$ is defined as
$$
(x,u,v)\mapsto(\phi^{-1}(x),u\circ d\phi,d((d\phi^{-1})^*)v).
$$
Here $(d\phi)^*:FU\to FM$ is a map defined as $(x,u)\mapsto(\phi(x),u\circ d\phi^{-1})$. Also, obviously, one has the commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}
 -FU & \to &FM \\
\,\downarrow & & \,\downarrow \\\
U & \to & M
\end{array}.
$$
That is, $\phi \circ \pi_U = \pi_M \circ (d\phi)^*$. All together, the value of $w_u((\phi^{-1})^*(x,u,v))$ is
$$
w_u((\phi^{-1})^*(x,u,v)) = u\circ d\phi\circ d\pi_U \circ d((d\phi^*))(v) \\
=u \circ d(\phi\circ \pi_U) \circ d((d\phi^{-1})^*) (v) \\
= u \circ d(\pi_M \circ (d\phi)^*) \circ d((d\phi^{-1})^*) (v) \\
= u\circ d\pi_M \circ d((d\phi)^*) \circ d((d\phi^{-1})^*) (v) = u\circ d\pi_M(v),
$$
So we get the desired equality.
Hence, $w_M$ is just $w_{U_j}$ glued together.
Remark 1. The notation here looks a bit messy, but if you use the element of $FM$ as $(x,u)$ where $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to T_x M$, some of the inverse will go away. I followed your convention in this proof.
Remark 2. Unlike $\mathbb{R}^n$, in $M$, you cannot just say that the fiber is $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Although $F_x M$ and $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic as vector space, there is no canonical isomorphism between them. In other words, there is no natural choice to which the identity $I\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ corresponds in $F_x M$. once you choose an element $u\in F_x M$, you get an isomorphism $\phi_u : F_x M \to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ where $u$ is mapped to the identity. $\phi_u(v)$ is then $u\circ v^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$.
On the other hand, on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is a very natural choice of the isomorphism $F\mathbb{R}^n\cong \mathbb{R}^n\times GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, due to the coordinate vector fields $\partial_{x_j}$. Here $I\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ corresponds to $T_x \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ mapping vectors $\partial_{x_1},\ldots,\partial_{x_n}$ to the standard basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$.
